# Android menuItem not displaying until you click on it....?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I believe my question is simple for most experienced Android developers but I cannot figure it out.

I am trying to set the name in a menuItem and make the text WHITE colored.

The text gets displayed only if I click on the menuItem, or rather when I click on the menuItem, the text turns white and is readable.

Any useful help how I can make the text white and visible all the time in the menuItem?

item.setTitle(this.task.getName()); is supposed to be white and visible all the time in the menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate( R.menu.show_task_feedback_menu, menu );
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
switch ( item.getItemId() )
{
  case R.id.show_task_feedback_menu_add_feedback:  
    item.setTitle(this.task.getName()); <------------- Here is the problem!!!!!!!!!!
    this.startTaskFeedback();
    return true;
  default: return true;
}
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
android:id="@+id/show_task_feedback_menu_add_feedback"
>
</item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same question over and over, after my suggestion below I noticed you asked this same question 3 times already.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, seems to me you just need to add the following line to your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/show_task_feedback_menu_add_feedback"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"> <!-- this line -->
    </item>

</menu>
```

Not sure I understand which text you want to set to white...